# Problems setting up mass email

Tags: apex, massemailmessage

I would like to set up a mass email to a number of patients that have a certain disease. I have the following set up.

My Objects are:

**Disease__c**: 
Name,
Category

**Contact**:
Name,
Email

**Patient**:
Contact Lookup,
Disease Master-Detail (where disease__c is master)

So, I now want to send an email to all Patients that have disease x.
Here is my code so far:

```
List <Id> targetObjects = new List <Id>;
List <Id> whatids = new List <Id>;
//I know this query is totally wrong!
targetObjects = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Contact.Name == Patient.Name && Patient.Disease = 'x'];
for {Disease__c d : disease)
{
  Messaging.Massemailmessage email = new Messaging.Massemailmessage();
  email.setDescription('Send disease information');
  email.setTargetObjectIds(targetObjects);
  //I guess here I want to also add the IDs of Disease__c and Patient__c as I want to include merge fields from those objects?
  email.setWhatIds(whatids);
}
```

I know how to do this successfully using single email, but I just cannot get it right using mass email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no it's not a duplicate. Here the problem is the query and then passing it to the mass email.

Comment: The answer is the same: create a new List (`List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>`) to hold all the emails to send and then pass the List into `Messaging.sendEmail()` to send them

Comment: but I don't understand - I want to use Massemailmessage as there might be cases in which I will send out 1000 emails. single email message only handles a fraction of those. As far as I understand, I cannot pass a list of email messages to massemailmessage, but i need to pass the contact object, is that correct?